# What am I doing wrong with this boolean

Tags: python, syntax-error, boolean-logic

I have the following code, but I'm getting a syntax error, what's wrong? :

```
name = 'Carol'
age = 3000
if name == 'Alice':
    print('Hi, Alice')
        if age < 12:
              print('You are not Alice, kiddo.')
              else:
                  print('You are neither Alice nor a little kid.')
    

syntax error line 7(the else operator)
```

Comment: Please reformat your question and add the `python` tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As describer by @Peter indentation is quite important in python and one indentation can lead to different results or error. In your code, the `else` is not indented properly. It must be indented same as that of `if`. This is causing syntax error in your code.

This will give you the result you are looking for:

```
name = 'Carol'
age = 3000
if name == 'Alice':
    print('Hi, Alice')
elif age < 12:
    print('You are not Alice, kiddo.')
else:
    print('You are neither Alice nor a little kid.')
```

Comment: Got it! Thank you so much.  I went back to the instructions I was looking at from http://automatetheboringstuff.com/2e/chapter2/ and just saw how I misread the instructions.  Thank you all so very much for helping me out!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the python code in a format that will run.

```
name = 'Carol' 
age = 3000 
if name == 'Alice':  
    print('Hi, Alice')        
if age < 12: 
    print('You are not Alice, kiddo.')
else:
    print('You are neither Alice nor a little kid.')
```

https://realpython.com/run-python-scripts/ will show you how to run the program.  Welcome to the world of programming!

Comment: Thank you I'll look into this page as well thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Indentation in Python is extremely important, it is unclear if the problem with the indentation is due to how you have created the question or how you have actually formatted the code. Your example could mean either of the following:

```
name = 'Carol'
age = 3000
if name == 'Alice':
    print('Hi, Alice')
    if age < 12:
        print('You are not Alice, kiddo.')
    else:
        print('You are neither Alice nor a little kid.')
```

which outputs nothing (for the supplied variables)

or

```
name = 'Carol'
age = 3000
if name == 'Alice':
    print('Hi, Alice')
if age < 12:
    print('You are not Alice, kiddo.')
else:
    print('You are neither Alice nor a little kid.')
```

Which outputs "You are neither Alice nor a little kid." which could be a blatant lie as the following would output the same:

```
name = 'Alice'
age = 3000
if name == 'Alice':
    print('Hi, Alice')
if age < 12:
    print('You are not Alice, kiddo.')
else:
    print('You are neither Alice nor a little kid.')
```

Although this is a trivial example, as you can see, the output that these would generate is very different. I suspect from the outputs generated, what you were looking for is the first example above.

A bit of guesswork here, but did you paste the code into vi? If so vi has a tendancy to try to be helpful and indent code, but this can result in text/code with each line having an ever increasing indentation (which can be modifed by changing the vi configuration).